# Как при наведении на кнопку воспроизвести анимацию один раз?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Создаю меню для первой игры. Сделал анимацию при наведении на кнопку, но она воспроизводится бесконечно.Как можно сделать, чтобы она воспроизводилась 1 раз?

Answer (score 1):

[IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html)

Метод вызывается на событие входа курсора в хитбокс `UI` объекта.